# What is implementation principle of std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts in rust

Tags: rust, std

my rust version is 1.64.0.

In file  "C:\Users\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\ptr\mod.rs".
I see the implementation of std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts:

```
pub const fn slice_from_raw_parts<T>(data: *const T, len: usize) -> *const [T] {
    from_raw_parts(data.cast(), len)
}
```

In file "C:\Users\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\ptr\metadata.rs". I see the implementation of from_raw_parts:

```
pub const fn from_raw_parts<T: ?Sized>(
    data_address: *const (),
    metadata: <T as Pointee>::Metadata,
) -> *const T {
    // SAFETY: Accessing the value from the `PtrRepr` union is safe since *const T
    // and PtrComponents<T> have the same memory layouts. Only std can make this
    // guarantee.
    unsafe { PtrRepr { components: PtrComponents { data_address, metadata } }.const_ptr }
}
```

The function slice_from_raw_parts return type is *const [T], the function from_raw_parts return type is *const T.

Why function slice_from_raw_parts  can directly return function from_raw_parts's result?

They have different return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different `T`s.

First, `slice_from_raw_parts` is essentially this:

```
pub const fn slice_from_raw_parts<T_slice_from>(data: *const T_slice_from, len: usize) -> *const [T_slice_from] {
    from_raw_parts::<T_from>(data.cast(), len)
}
```

Note that `T_from` and `T_slice_from` doesn't have to be the same.

Now about `from_raw_parts`:

```
pub const fn from_raw_parts<T_from: ?Sized>(
    data_address: *const (),
    metadata: <T_from as Pointee>::Metadata,
) -> *const T_from {
    // impl omitted
}
```

From this you can see that `*const T_from` must be equal (or coercible to) `*const [T_slice_from]`, i.e. `T_from = [T_slice_from]`, which is possible since `from_raw_parts` allows its generic type to be non-`Sized`.

And, to make the picture complete, - the `metadata`: it is typed as `usize` in the caller and as `<T_from as Pointee>::Metadata`, i.e. `<[T_slice_from] as Pointee>::Metadata`, in the callee. There's no explicit documented implementation of `Pointee` for slices, but [documentation for trait itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/ptr/trait.Pointee.html) mentions that slice's metadata is `usize` - which matches our observations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have som question.The function from_raw_parts return *const T_from，T_from is non-Sized，I see the impl , it return PtrRepr.const_ptr，after the function return, the union PtrRepr will be free, PtrRepr.components.metadata will not be access any more?  That mean *const T_from only have own the PtrRepr.components.data_address?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean here. Why do you think that `components.metadata` will be freed, but not `components.data_address`?

Comment: Such as i call from_raw_parts(0x1234 , 1),  the function will construct a union struct PtrRepr, and set PtrRepr.components.data_address=0x1234, PtrRepr.components.metadata=1，and then return PtrRepr.const_ptr, now PtrRepr.const_ptr is equal to 0x1234. In this situation, the function return 0x1234, after the function return, the union PrRepr will destory, because it malloc in stack ,not in heap. The caller will just get 0x1234，but miss the metadata？

Comment: "now PtrRepr.const_ptr is equal to 0x1234" - that's not correct. `PtrRepr.const_ptr` is a fat pointer, therefore it has a size of two `usize`s, therefore it contains data from both `PtrRepr.components.data_address` and `PtrRepr.components.metadata`.

Comment: PtrRepr.const_ptr has type *const T. now this T is inferred to be [T], so PtrRepr.const_ptr is assume to be a fat pointer?

Comment: `PtrRepr.const_ptr` has type `*const T_from`, that is, `*const [T_slice_from]`, which is fat, yes.

Answer (score 0):

`T` of `from_raw_parts()` is inferred to be `[T]` of `slice_from_raw_parts()`, so they have compatible return types.

Comment: You mean *const T can auto convert to *const [T]?  I think they have much different. *const [T] is an slice ptr, it has ptr and len，but *const T，is just a nomal ptr. In function from_raw_parts implementation, i only see it return PtrRepr.const_ptr, but not retun the entire PtrRepr.

Comment: @bobpsv No. I mean that the `T` of `slice_from_raw_parts()` is not the same `T` of `from_raw_parts()`, they are inferred to be different types.